# Cannot we use break statement in a lambda(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

Consider this

```
List<int> intList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

            int j = 0;
            intList.ForEach(i =>
                {
                    if (i.Equals(1))
                    {
                        j = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            );
```

Throwing error: **No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue**

But the below works

```
foreach(int i in intList)
{
j = i; break;
}
```

Why so. Am I making any mistake.

Thanks

Comment: An argument against using a ForEach method http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that the purpose of the ForEach method is to call the lambda method you pass to it on each item in the list. If you need to break out of a loop as part of your loop processing, you have to use a classic loop.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of being modded down for "going outside of the scope of the question", I'm going to ask what it is the OP is *really* trying to accomplish.

The code in question is trying to determine if the integer (1) exists anywhere in the list. But it seems clear to me that the code above is just a demonstration, not the actual problem.

Using "ForEach" to iterate over the list to determine if something is in the list is the wrong way of going about this. Instead, using one of the many "Find" functions is the better approach.

For example, going along with the OP's original code:

```
 j = intList.Find(i => i.Equals(1));
```

This would do *exactly* the same thing as the above proposed code. It would iterate over the list, (and if possible) return the lambda matched value to "j" and break early.

```
 intList.Exists(i => i.Equals(1));
```

Would *effectively* do the same thing. It would iterate over the list and return a TRUE if it was able to find if 1 exists and "break" early. (otherwise it iterates over the whole list and returns FALSE.)

```
 intList.FindIndex(i => i.Equals(1));
```

Would return the Index position of the FIRST instance that matches the lambda. (again breaking early if possible)

```
 intList.FindAll(i => i.Equals(1));
```

Returns a sub-list of all the items in the intList that match the lambda expression. (naturally this has to iterate over the whole list, regardless...)

Newbie: Is there a reason why you cannot use any of these built-in methods? Just curious, as I'd like to help.

Cheers.

Comment: You won't be downmodded by me; those are all helpful hints, scope question notwithstanding. +1 That said, I think the questioner was simply providing a breaking example rather than actually trying to do it that way. Or maybe I'm reading more into it than necessary, I dunno. :)

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate the vote of confidence.  [I already gave you an up-vote, btw.]  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `ForEach` method is not a real `foreach` loop. You can simulate the effect by throwing an exception inside the lambda and catching it outside the call to `ForEach`.

Comment: You should use "return" instead. It's an anonymous function, and behaves like one.

Comment: @Computer Guru, each element is processed with a distinct call to the lambda. The lambda always returns after processing each element. Invoking an explicit `return` will therefore go unnoticed and `ForEach` will continue looping.

Comment: @Marcelo is correct, which is why I deleted my answer. I can't upvote this, though, as exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control.

Comment: @Adam, I agree in principle, but I'm also a pragmatist. I'll even use `goto` if it makes my program cleaner (it almost never does, but there have been a handful of occasions where it made things turn out just right).

Comment: @Marcelo: As a fellow pragmatist, `ForEach` obviously isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: @Adam, Props to you for acknowledging your mistake and deleting your answer. And good on you for knowing that Exceptions shouldn't typically be used for flow control.

Comment: I guess it depends on what the OP wants. I figure(d) he meant a `break;` of the single lamda and a `continue;` for the bigger picture, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

The break statement only works in the same function scope as the foreach statement.  The lambda starts a new function scope, thus the break does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SkipWhile()` and `Take()` extension methods to mimic what you're doing, but it isn't good or readable...

```
public void SO2857489()
{
    var intList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    var j = 0;
    intList.SkipWhile(i => i != 1).Take(1).ToList().ForEach(i => j = i);
    Console.WriteLine(j);
}
```

The `SkipWhile()` here does the job of your `if (i.Equals(1))` statement and the `Take(1)` does the job of the `break`.  Like I said, it isn't pretty.